# What are the normal subgroups of a direct product?

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G \times H$, and let $\pi_1: G \times H \to G$ and $\pi_2: G \times H \to H$ be the canonical projections. Then $\pi_1(N)$ is normal in $G$ and $\pi_2(N)$ is normal in $H$. What else can we say? I know that it is not true, in general, that $N \simeq \pi_1(N) \times \pi_2(N)$.

I'm particularly interested in the case where $G$ and $H$ are simple. In that case, $N \simeq \pi_1(N) \times \pi_2(N)$ except possibly in the case where $\pi_1(N) = G$ and $\pi_2(N) = H$. In that case, what do we know?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See [Goursat's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goursat_lemma).

Comment: Perfect! So in particular, if I understand correctly, if $G$ and $H$ are distinct simple groups, then it is true that for a normal subgroup $N$, $N \simeq \pi_1(N) \times \pi_2(N)$.

Comment: Wow, I never knew this had a name.

Answer (score 9):

If $G$ and $H$ are non-abelian simple groups and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G×H$, then $N$ is equal (not just isomorphic) to $1×1$, $1×H$, $G×1$, or $G×H$.  If $G$ and $H$ are simple groups but not isomorphic, then the same is true.  If $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic abelian simple groups, then $G×H$ is a two-dimensional vector space over some $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$, and so it has $1 + (p+1) + 1$ normal subgroups, $1$ of dimension $0$, $p+1$ of dimension $1$, and $1$ of dimension $2$.  Only in the last case can it happen that $N$ is not precisely equal to (and also not isomorphic to) $π_1(N)×π_2(N)$, but of course this happens for $p-1$ of the $1$-dimensional subspaces, the ones that have non-trivial projection onto both the $x$ and $y$ axes.

Answer (score 9):

Let $N$ be normal in $G\times H$. For $n=(n_1, n_2) \in N$ and $(g, 1) \in G\times H$ follows $([n_1, g], 1) = (n_1^{-1}n_1^g, 1) = n^{-1}\cdot n^{(g, 1)} \in N$ (taking the notations used in group theory: $n^g = g^{-1}ng$ etc), i.e., $[\pi_1(N), G]\times 1 \le N$ (where $[A, B]$ denotes the subgroup generated by the commutators $[a, b]$ with $a \in A, b\in B$). Also $1\times[\pi_2(N), H] \le N$, hence $[\pi_1(N), G]\times[\pi_2(N), H] \le N$.

As $[\pi_1(N), G]$ is normal in $G$, one can easily deduce for $G, H$ simple the cases described by Jack Schmidt (and also what happens in the missing case that one of the two groups is abelian but the other one not).

Answer (score 6):

The following corollary is from *[Normal Subgroup Growth of Linear Groups: the $(G_2, F_4, E_8)$-Theorem](http://tinyurl.com/nsglinear)*, by Michael Larsen and Alex Lubotzky.

> **Corollary 1.4**:
>   Let $G = A \times B$ be the product of two groups. If for every (finite index) normal subgroup $M \lhd A$, $Z(A/M) = \{ 1 \}$, then every (finite index) normal subgroup $N \lhd G$ is of the form $N = (N \cap A) \times (N \cap B)$.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly have other situations, even in the simple case. For instance 
if $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic, the diagonal maps onto each factor.

Comment: See Goursat's lemma ;-)

Comment: The diagonal's very rarely normal!