# If $G \times G \cong H \times H$, then is $G \cong H$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory, infinite-combinatorics

Let $G,H$ groups. Suppose that $G \times G \cong H \times H$. Then is necessarily $G \cong H$?

I know that if $G,H$ are finite groups then it is true (you show that the map $FinGrp \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, $A \mapsto \left|Hom(A,G)\right| $ determines $G$, and then $\left|Hom(A,G)\right|=\sqrt{\left|Hom(A,G\times G)\right|}=\sqrt{\left|Hom(A,H\times H)\right|}=\left|Hom(A,H)\right|$), so I am interested in the infinite case.

Note that the proof for the finite case also works for finite topological spaces, finite graphs, and maybe other categories I didn't consider. So I also interested on the analogous questions about infinite topological spaces, infinite graphs, or any other interesting category.

Comment: Notice that this question is answered by http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10128/when-is-a-isomorphic-to-a3. Indeed, if $A$ is an example of a group with $A \cong A \times A \times A$ but $A$ not isomorphic to $A \times A$, then the groups $G = A$ and $H = A \times A$ provide a counterexample.

Comment: For the record, a related question was: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/114139/can-we-ascertain-that-there-exist-an-epimorphism-g-rightarrow-h

Answer (score 8):

In a word, no, even if $G$ and $H$ are assumed to be abelian. A. L. S. Corner has various results showing how strangely infinitely generated abelian groups behave. In particular, `given a positive integer $q$, there exist standard abelian $p$-groups $G$ and $H$ with no elements of infinite height such that $G^n≅H^n$ if and only if $q$ divides $n$'. (I'm quoting from the review on mathscinet.) So taking $q=2$ gives a counterexample to the question. This result is in

> Corner, A. L. S.
>   On endomorphism rings of primary abelian groups.
>   Quart. J. Math. Oxford Ser. (2) 20 1969 277–296.

Answer (score 6):

Whether two (a) topological spaces, (b) metric spaces, or (c) groups $A$ and $B$, with isomorphic squares, are necessarily isomorphic, was Problem 77 (of Ulam) in [the Scottish book](http://kielich.amu.edu.pl/Stefan_Banach/pdf/ks-szkocka/ks-szkocka3ang.pdf). The following information is from the commentaries on Problem 77, by Mauldin for (a) and (b) and by Kaplansky for (c), in [*The Scottish Book: Mathematics from the Scottish Café*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3764330457), R. Daniel Mauldin, ed., 1981.

Mauldin gives a bibliography of 17 items for parts (a) and (b). The first counterexample for part (a), as well as a positive answer for two-dimensional compact manifolds, was given by R. H. Fox, On a problem of S. Ulam concerning Cartesian products, Fund. Math. 34 (1947), 278-287. The first counterexample to part (b) was given by G. Fournier, On a problem of S. Ulam, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 29 (1971), 622. Mauldin writes (in 1981):

> However, it is open whether there is an affirmative solution to (b) in the case that $A$ and $B$ are complete metric spaces. In fact, part (b) is open in the case where $A$ and $B$ are assumed to be compact.

The first counterexample for part (c) was given by B. Jónsson, On direct decomposition and torsion-free abelian groups, Math. Scand. 5 (1957), 230-235.

**P.S.** The positive result in the finite case, proved by counting homomorphisms, is due to [László Lovász](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A1szl%C3%B3_Lov%C3%A1sz); it applies to arbitrary finite structures, and it solved a problem of Tarski called the Unique Square Root Problem.