# Examples of groups such that order isomorphism of the subgroups of $G\times G$ and $H\times H$ does not imply isomorphism of $G$ and $H$

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, examples, order-theory, counterexamples

Let $G$ and $H$ be groups, $\operatorname{Sub}(G\times G)$ be the set of all subgroups of $G\times G$ and $\operatorname{Sub}(H\times H)$ be the set of all subgroups of $H\times H$. Assume there exists a bijection $\phi :\operatorname{Sub}(G\times G) \to \operatorname{Sub}(H\times H)$ such that always
$$A\le B~~\leftrightarrow~~\phi(A)\le\phi(B)$$

1) If $G$ and $H$ are infinite abelian groups, are they isomorphic?

2) If $G$ and $H$ are finite non-abelian non-simple groups, are they isomorphic?

---

**Edit**:

As shane.orourke's answer shows below and also by an example by Schmidt in

```
R. Schmidt. Der Untergruppenverband des direkten Produktes zweier isomorpher Gruppen. J. Algebra 73 (1981), 264–272.
```

The first question and has a negative answer. (Still I'm not sure if Schmidt's example is abelian)

The second question remains unanswered.

Comment: do you really mean "non-abelian non-simple"? this is a weird assumption.

Comment: yes, I have an answer for finite abelian or simple case already.

Comment: for finite abelian or simple they are isomorphic,

Comment: But it's weird to exclude them (for instance the question makes sense if $G$ is abelian and not $H$). You could just mention that the answer is yes in a few particular cases (e.g. when $G,H$ are both finite abelian)

Comment: @YvesCornulier: If $G$ is abelian and $H$ is not; they are not isomorphic, nothing remains to ask. My limitations generalizes the question in title.

Comment: I don't agree with "nothing remains to ask": in principle you might have $G$ abelian, $H$ not abelian, but $G^2$ and $H^2$ (or $G$ and $H$) having isomorphic lattice of subgroups.

Comment: yes whether the sturucture of $\operatorname{Sub}(G\times G)$ reveals abelian-ness or simple-ness, can be interesting. But my question is about whether it reveals the structure of $G$ completely (and not partially).

Comment: btw, it reveals abeliannes

Answer (score 4):

The answer to the first question is no. A. L. S. Corner showed that (quoting from the mathscinet review): `given a positive integer $q$, there exist standard abelian $p$-groups $G$ and $H$ with no elements of infinite height such that $G^n\cong H^n$ if and only if $q$ divides $n$'.

So if $q=2$ we get $G\times G\cong H\times H$ -- and certainly a bijection as required by the question -- even though $G\not\cong H$.

This result is in the paper

> A. L. S. Corner On endomorphism rings of primary abelian groups.
>   Quart. J. Math. Oxford Ser. (2) 20 1969 277–296.

(This is basically a duplicate of my answer to [If $G \times G \cong H \times H$, then is $G \cong H$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/150793/if-g-times-g-cong-h-times-h-then-is-g-cong-h/150795#150795); this question in turn was a duplicate of [when is A isomorphic to A^3?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10128/when-is-a-isomorphic-to-a3).)

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is a standard group?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek If I'm not mistaken, a standard abelian $p$-group $G$ is one that coincides with one of its `standard' subgroups, namely $G_p$ which consists of elements of order dividing $p$, or $G^p$ which consists of $p$th powers.

Comment: Thank you, however, this does not seem to work. If $G=G_p$, $G$ is of exponent $p$ and thus a direct sum of $\kappa$ copies of the $p$-element cyclic group for some $\kappa$, and if $G=G^p$, it is divisible and thus a direct sum of $\kappa$ copies of the Prüfer $p$-group. In either case, the isomorphism type is uniquely determined by $\kappa$, which easily implies $G^n\simeq H^n\iff G\simeq H$. Could it be that the meaning is $G=G_{p^k}$ for some $k$, i.e., that $G$ has a finite exponent?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek You could be right, I don't have the paper to hand.