# generality of the lattice of normal subgroups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, lattices, counterexamples, lattice-theory

Let $(X,\le)$ a (finite) modular lattice. Is there a (finite) group $G$ such that the lattice of all normal subgroups of $G$ is isomorphic to $(X,\le)$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many counterexamples.  Let $M_n$ be the lattice of height two with $n$ atoms.  Say the lattice of normal subgroups of the group $G$ is isomorphic with $M_n$.  Let $A,B$ be two atoms in this lattice.  Then $AB=G$ and $A \cap B=1$.  So, $G=A \times B$.  As each normal subgroup of $A$ is normal in $A \times B$, we see that $A$ and $B$ are simple.  Unless $A,B$ have the same prime order $p$, the only normal subgroups of $G$ are $A$ and $B$, and $n=2$.  If $A,B$ both have order $p$ then $n=p+1$.

Comment: related: http://mathoverflow.net/a/23705/47958